# Is Exception handling required in Spring Transaction?

Tags: java, spring, exception, transactions

I am having a doubt in exception handling with a Transaction. To state clearly my problem I would like to show my configuration:

```
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

<bean id="transactionInterceptor" abstract="true" class="org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionProxyFactoryBean">
    <property name="transactionManager" ref="transactionManager" />
    <property name="transactionAttributeSource">
        <bean class="org.springframework.transaction.annotation.AnnotationTransactionAttributeSource" />
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="baseService" abstract="true">
    <property name="daoProvider" ref="daoProvider" />
</bean>

<bean id="customerService" parent="transactionInterceptor">
    <property name="target">
        <bean class="com.edfx.adb.service.CustomerService" parent="baseService" />
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="daoProvider" class="com.edfx.adb.dao.provider.DaoProvider">   
    <property name="customerDao" ref="customerDao" />
</bean>

<bean id="customerDao" class="com.edfx.adb.dao.CustomerDao">
    <constructor-arg value="#{T(com.edfx.adb.persist.entity.Customer)}" />
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>
```

The active transaction class is:

```
@Transactional
public class CustomerService extends BaseService implements ICustomerService {

    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public Customer getCustomerById(String id) {
        return getDaoProvider().getCustomerDao().getCustomerById(id);
    }

    @Transactional(readOnly = false, propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED, rollbackFor = { Throwable.class })
    public void addNewCustomer(CustomerDTO customerDTO) {
        Customer customer = new Customer();

        customer.setCustomerId(customerDTO.getCustomerId());
        customer.setCustomerName(customerDTO.getCustomerName());
        customer.setActive(customerDTO.isActive());

        getDaoProvider().getCustomerDao().save(customer);
    }
}
```

My doubts lies in the method `addNewCustomer`. I have set `rollbackFor = { Throwable.class }`.

How does it work?

Also do I need to explicitly handle exception like:

```
@Transactional(readOnly = false, propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED, rollbackFor = { Throwable.class })
public boolean addNewCustomer(CustomerDTO customerDTO) {
    Customer customer = new Customer();

    customer.setCustomerId(customerDTO.getCustomerId());
    customer.setCustomerName(customerDTO.getCustomerName());
    customer.setActive(customerDTO.isActive());

    try {
        getDaoProvider().getCustomerDao().save(customer);
    } catch (Throwable throwable) {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Forcefully I have created an exception by deleting a column from the customer table, BUT that exception wasn't catch in the try-catch block, rather I can catch that exception from the managed bean where I have invoked the `addNewCustomer` method.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is an excerpt from Spring docs

> In its default configuration, the Spring Framework's transaction
>   infrastructure code only marks a transaction for rollback in the case
>   of runtime, unchecked exceptions; that is, when the thrown exception
>   is an instance or subclass of RuntimeException. (Errors will also - by
>   default - result in a rollback). Checked exceptions that are thrown
>   from a transactional method do not result in rollback in the default
>   configuration.

You set rollbackFor = Throwable.class, now Spring will rollback for any Exception / Error. By default, whether we like it or not, Spring will rollback only for RuintimeException, and commit otherwise

Comment: Forcefully I have created an exception by deleting a column from the customer table, BUT that exception wasn't catch in the try-catch block, rather I can catch that exception from the managed bean where I have invoked the `addNewCustomer` method.

Comment: Actually in your concrete case rollbackFor = Throwable.class makes no sense since addNewCustomer cannot throw any checked Exception since it does not declare any, and RuntimeExceptions are caught by default.

Comment: thank you for the explanation. Could please tell me, is the spring's xml configuration okay?

Comment: seems OK. But I suggest to take a look at http://static.springsource.org/spring-data/data-jpa/docs/current/reference/html/ in case you havent yet. New way to work with databases.

Comment: @Evgeniy Dorofeev - Which version of Spring does [this](http://static.springsource.org/spring-data/data-jpa/docs/current/reference/html/) link as you commented in your latest comment of this answer refer to? I found it very interesting. I have tried with the Spring version 3.0.2 but there are no such classes or interfaces regarding to this version. Please let me know. I'm very much eager to use that approach.

Answer (score 6):

The Spring framework only throws RuntimeExceptions, technically you never have to catch any exceptions.

Comment: Thank you. Is the spring's xml configuration is okay? The hibernate's save method thorws Hibernate exception. Don't I need to handle it?

Comment: I am not getting any exception. I am writing the code, while writing I was curious about the exception handling. I am trying to make my code error free.

Comment: Somehow I am able to throw an exception, by deleting a column in the customer table. But strange the exception couldn't be handled.